# Show product default_code in purchase order line

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

When creating a new purchase order I want to remove the `product_name` under the `product_id` so for that I did this function:

```python
class snc_product(osv.osv):
    _name='product.product'
    _inherit='product.product'

    def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        return_val = super(snc_product, self).name_get(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
        res = []
        def _name_get(d):
            code = d.get('code','')
            if d.get('variants'):
                code = code + ' - %s' % (d['variants'],)
            return (d['id'], code)
        for product in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            res.append((product.id, (product.code)))
        return res or return_val
```

The problem now is even under description I'm getting the default_code instead of the name.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOSjZ.jpg

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: Please format your code to make it somehow readble

Comment: Does anyone how to solve it???

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you redefined also the `name_get()` method of the `purchase.order.line` model. The second column, named 'Description' is showing the `name` field ot the `purchase.order.line` model. That's why I suppose you redefined it.

Your solution is working for me - I have the product code in the first column and the description in the second. Only one thing - you don't need this internal `_name_get()` method as you don't use it.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```python
 from openerp.osv import osv, fields


    class snc_product(osv.osv):
        _name = 'product.product'
        _inherit = 'product.product'

        def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
            return_val = super(snc_product, self).name_get(cr, uid, ids,
                                                           context=context)
            res = []
            for product in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
                res.append((product.id, (product.code)))
            return res or return_val

    snc_product()
```

Comment: It's your code without the internal _name_get method. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but I have tried this code and it didn't work are you working on odoo 8.0

Comment: Yes, I'm working on Odoo 8. What do you mean by "it didn't work"? It gave you the same result as your code or what?

Comment: When I have tried this code i'm still getting the product code n the first column and the second column

Comment: That's what I told you since the beginning :) Your problem is not in this code. Please read again my answer and check if I'm right - I suppose that you also redefined the `name_get()` method of the **purchase.order.line** model, not only of the **product.product** model.